# When is it appropriate to answer the same question twice?

Tags: discussion

I just did on the question [Responsive Web Design - what should happen when the mobile device is rotated?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24255/responsive-web-design-what-should-happen-when-the-mobile-device-is-rotated), but got advised to edit my first answer. But my first answer is from early august this year, and 4 months have passed since then. So I thought I would give it a second answer which answers the question in a different way and with a reference (this time).

Is this how it is supposed to be answering the second time - or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sanity test is basically would it make sense for you to post the second answer if someone else posted the first? Would it be better to edit the earlier post to add in some info (minor updates, a new relevant article, something like that), or does your new answer stand on it's own?

You should always try to make your answers as comprehensive as possible, but when you've got two competing or otherwise different ideas. In the linked post, you've really got two answers there, and the first sort of conflicts with the later (IMO better) answer.

A third option is to make a new answer and *delete* the old one; generally you should only do this if your first answer is plain wrong and you have a separate answer (not an edit) which you believe is correct (I don't think that's necessarily called for in this case, just pointing it out).

Comment: I would add that being proactive about answering questions is generally preferable. If that means writing another answer, go ahead and do it. The more knowledge you can contribute, the better.

Comment: Thanx, I think I got the picture now. Good answer, Ben, and a nice comment Rahul.